# How to write a vendor programme/module for ZFT

Tags: zend-framework2, composer-php

I would like to write a Zend Framework 2 vendor module, hosted on github, installable via composer and given to the world at large!

Now while I have no problems writing modules, where I am struggling is the mechanics around this.

My initial instinct would be to do something like this:

1. Set up a zend framework 2 skeleton app
2. Add my module as a normal module
3. Navigate to the module folder and create a git repo
4. Work on the module and update the module to my gitto...

Now logic tells me this is not the right way to go. So I am thinking, maybe I write the module as a stand alone outside of the skeleton app, push to the gito, and then pull from the gito to a working applicaiton...

If you can direct me to a tutorial, please let me know or if you can confirm or deny my proposed thinking that would be great too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You probably need some app around your module to check if it works, however that shouldn't affect the way you create that module.

When it comes to Zend Framework 2 integrating modules, all you really need is a class that is called `SomeNameSpace\Module` which must be autoloadable via Composer. Note that there is NO requirement to place this file at a certain location. ZF2 will detect that you are using it with Composer and simply check with `class_exists()` instead of trying to locate a file, include it and then check for the class.

This class should reveal some configuration info about your module in the way ZF2 expects modules to do this, i.e. add bootstrap event listeners, return configuration data via `getConfig()` etc. It need not return anything for `getAutoloaderConfig()`, because that's what Composer is for.

To add the module to the ZF2 application you add the `SomeNameSpace` name to the file `config/application.config.php`:

```
 return array(
     'modules' => array(
         'OtherStuffForTheDemoApp',
         'SomeNameSpace' # this enables your module in your demo app 
                         # and anywhere else where it's being used
     ),
```

ZF2 will see the module mentioned, try to instantiate `SomeNameSpace\Module`, ask it about all the configuration you defined, possibly calling the hook functions like `onBootstrap()` you provided there - and that's about it. Your module is responsible for doing the rest, i.e. provide a service manager configuration, provide controllers etc. All classes are autoloaded by Composer.

I believe the question of how to expose resources like images of a module hasn't been answered by Zend itself - at least I saw these questions being raised, but unanswered in the most current version of the documentation: http://framework.zend.com/manual/current/en/modules/zend.module-manager.intro.html

The organisation of files inside your module is completely up to you, although it seems common practice to place the source in a folder named `src`, tests probably go into `tests`.