# ZF2 Modules Development - Host using GIT and Composer

Tags: git, zend-framework2, composer-php, bitbucket

I am developing modules for ZF2, individual modules are hosted in its own repository space, here is my structure

```
module
|__ User
    |___ config
    |___ src
    |___ Module.php
    |___ composer.json
    |___ .git
__ Theme
    |___ config
    |___ src
    |___ Module.php
    |___ composer.json
    |___ .git
```

`User` Module is hosted on `bitbucket.org/example/user`, `Theme` is hosted on `bitbucket.org/example/theme` and so on.

User module has dependency with `DoctrineORMModule`, when i include the dependency using `composer.json` It creates the vendor directory within the module and install the files, here is the directory structure after adding the dependency in composer.json of User Module.

```
module
|__ User
    |___ config
    |___ src
    |___ vendor
    |___ Module.php
    |___ composer.json
    |___ .git
__ Theme
    |___ config
    |___ src
    |___ Module.php
    |___ composer.json
    |___ .git
```

If you noticed it added vendor directory inside the user module, It is normal to go with this approach for development? I was expecting the dependent module to be installed/copied in root vendor directory and not in module directory, the problem for me with this approach is that i do not want vendor inside the module directory, this way if i have shared dependency it will duplicate in multiple directories? what is the best of developing multiple modules in ZF2?

Thanks.

Comment: This shouldn't happen. Which folder are you in when you run the composer install command?

Comment: In the module/User directory.

Comment: Then that's the problem. Only run composer commands from your project root.

Comment: I got composer.json per module, If i run it from root, how does composer install dependencies specified within the module composer.json?

Comment: You should be installing your modules using composer as well, then composer will put them and their dependencies in vendor.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this question has a lot answered already here: [How to write a vendor programme/module for ZFT](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29610304/how-to-write-a-vendor-programme-module-for-zft/29613488#29613488)

Basically you wouldn't put the composer packages into the `modules` folder, but let Composer put them into the `vendor` directory. This will make the installation of a modules dependency unnecessary, because all dependencies will be tackled in one go by Composer for the main application.

Editing the packages there is mainly a question of what works nice - you might be happy by using `composer update --prefer-source`, which will clone the git repositories into the folders, and you are able to work with them there. Alternatively you can apply any method you want, like using symlinks etc., if you want to have these repositories anywhere else. Composer won't mind - if it finds the repository inside the path, it will use it.

Note however that it might be dangerous if you carelessly run the update without having everything committed.

Additionally, it might be a problem if you forget to commit an important file - it will work on your machine, because the file is there, but it's not in the repository, so it will be missed everywhere else.

Comment: Thanks @Sven, I don't mind developing module from vendor directory as long as it works, I tested your approach and it works.